# Service Reference with relative path

Tags: c#, asp.net, service

I have a service that can be running locally on my website or on a different server. I access it in my code using a service reference so I can point to either location. When I declare the client and specify an external server like `"https://differentserver.com/service.svc"` it works fine, but how do I declare it locally? I can't use localhost because the website is not guaranteed to be the default website. If I try to use the full url of the server that the website is currently on like `"https://devwebsite/service.svc"` I get:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 173.8.5.218:443

How do I get around this?

Comment: I don't see how the web.config would be of help in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added 127.0.0.1 devwebsite.com to my hosts file and used the full url.